# NodeJS memory heapUsed is constantly increasing, is it normal?

Tags: node.js

I have this little piece of code:

```
function concatena(a){
    var resultado = "";
    for(var i=0; i< a; i++){
        resultado = resultado + " " + "hola mundo";
    }
    return resultado;
}

function main(){
    var cadena = ""
    for(var i=0; i< 1024; i++){
        cadena = concatena(1024);

        // Print memory usage
        const used = process.memoryUsage();
        console.log('\ncadena.length:', cadena.length);

        console.log('\memory usage:');
        for (let key in used) {
            console.log(`\t${key} ${Math.round(used[key] / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100} MB`);
        }           

    }   
}

main();
```

On first iteration I have this memory usage:

```
cadena.length: 11264
memory usage:
        rss 21.3 MB
        heapTotal 9.23 MB
        heapUsed 3.75 MB
        external 0.01 MB
```

On last one, I have this:

```
cadena.length: 11264
memory usage:
        rss 30.8 MB
        heapTotal 16.23 MB
        heapUsed 7.16 MB
        external 0.01 MB
```

Why is memory heapUsed, heapTotal and rss increasing if "cadena" is always the same length and the same variable?

As far as memory heapUsed is always increasing in an infinite process it will finally crash, how can I solve this?. This would mean that an infinite loop could crash a program which does not sound logic at all.

Thank you.
J. Pablo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cadena = concatena(1024);` allocates a new string on the heap every single time, leaving the previous duplicate sting floating without a reference. Node will garbage collect if you give it time, but as you're running a synchronous loop it blocks other events until complete, including the garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks. Why is doing this?, "cadena" is always the same varible. How can I solve it?

Comment: It's the same variable, but every time `concatena()` executes, a new string is allocated here: `var resultado = ""`. This instantiates a new string requiring its own space on the heap, separate from the existing one of length 11264, and then keeps adding to it. When it returns, it returns this new string which is assigned to `cadena`, and the string that was previously assigned to `cadena` (with its own space on the heap) is now left free floating without a reference and needs to be garbage collected.

Comment: So, there is no other way to do it without having this issue?. I mean, if I declare "resultado" as global variable, so that there is no need to instantiate a new "resultado" variable on every execution of "concatena()" but just one (the global one), the problem remains the same.

Comment: it's not the variable itself getting instantiated, that's simply not how that works - you declare the variable once, presumably allocating space for a pointer internally (an int), and then every time you set it to a string literal i.e. `" hola mundo"` it must allocate a new chunk of memory for that new string and set the variable to point to that new chunk of memory. whether you declare the variable globally or not is largely irrelevant

Comment: there are definitely workarounds to this but i'd need more information on what you're actually trying to achieve, because repeatedly building and discarding very large strings isn't what i'd call a use case and i'm not sure what to optimize it for

Comment: it was just a test. I guess in C it is not working like this, there is no problem in doing this, as far as you leave "concatena()" internal function variables are destroyed.

Comment: C does not use a garbage collector because programmers are expected to manage their own memory usage. It's likely an implementation of this function in C would manually deallocate/destroy the memory at the start or end of the `concatena()` function, at which point obviously this won't be an issue